# How to set bandwidth limit using linux tc

Tags: linux, filter, tc, bandwidth

In my linux router:

1. interface eth1 total bandwidth is 1gbit
2. I want to divide 1140kbit to GroupA, divide 150kbit to GroupB
3. Set users 10.10.10.158, 10.10.21.5,  10.10.21.6 to GroupB
4. Each user has no more than 128kbit bandwidth
5. And three users has no more than 150kbit total bandwidth.

Following are what I set:

```
sudo tc qdisc del dev eth1 root 2>/dev/null

sudo tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1: htb default 2
sudo tc class add dev eth1 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1gbit ceil 1gbit
sudo tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 10kbps ceil 10kbps

sudo tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 1140kbit ceil 1140kbit
sudo tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 128kbit ceil 128kbit

sudo tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:20 classid 1:21 htb rate 128kbit ceil 128kbit
sudo tc filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.10.10.158/32 flowid 1:21

sudo tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:20 classid 1:22 htb rate 128kbit ceil 128kbit
sudo tc filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.10.21.5/32 flowid 1:22

sudo tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:20 classid 1:23 htb rate 128kbit ceil 128kbit
sudo tc filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32 match ip dst 10.10.21.6/32 flowid 1:23
```

However, I found three users total bandwidth is about 376kbit.
What should I do to acheive my goal?